# Obj C codebase and unit test cases in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, unit-testing, private-members, private-methods

I have an objective c code base and I am writing snapshot test cases in swift. I have certain functions and variable which are declared in .m class. How I can access those variables from swift test class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift) to expose the Objective-C entities that you want to use in your Swift tests. You may already have one set up (as explained in the link, Xcode offers to create one when you add a Swift file to an Objective-C project); if so, you may just need to update the file to add headers that aren't currently included. If you don't have one, the link I provided will show you how to create one.